# How to generate a pop-up window if a user is not logged in?

Tags: php, javascript

In an HTML page:

```
<a href="/files/getfile.php?name=abc.zip">file download</a>
```

in PHP script(getfile.php):

```
if('notlogged')
{
  echo 'please, loggin~'; //pop up, possible?
  return false;
}
```

So my question is, When user click the anchor tag, can I pop up a login window if user didn't log?

I knew I can pre-check in Javascript before calling the PHP script whether user logged or not.

But, it's not my case for use; the PHP script should have to throw pop up code.

The page user is viewing should not changed — just pop up login window.

Comment: Why do not not generate link dynamically based on user's login status?

Comment: hm... it's good idea, but the number of link not one. so it's a bit complicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP script is executed on the server site, so it cannot generate a popup window when the link is clicked. You can accomplish your goal one of two ways:

1. Use Javascript to generate an AJAX call to your PHP script, and popup a login window as necessary.
2. Use header( "Location: /your/login/script.php" ) in getfile.php to send the user to a login page, but with no popup.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php if(loggedin){?>
  <a href="/files/getfile.php?name=abc.zip">file download</a>
<?php
} else {
?>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="popup();">file download</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think this is a great solution too~ ^^;